# Detect when popup window closes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I open a popup window leading to google:

```
var popup = window.open("http://google.com", "_blank", "width=600,height=600");
```

How do I detect when user has closed this window?

For example:

```
if (popup == 'closed') {
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: The popup can talk to the window that opened it via the `window.opener` variable. If you are coding the popup as well then that might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A window has a `closed` field that indicates wether it has been closed or not, so if you want to execute something when the user closes the popup, you can do something like this:

```
var popup = window.open(...)
var intervalRef = setInterval(function() {   
    if(popup.closed) {  
        clearInterval(intervalRef);  
        // Do whatever you want to do when the user closes the popup here 
    }
}, 100);
```